# how to remove a style from html link's child tag?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have the following html code:

```
<a href="#idSomething"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down fa-3x"></i></a>
```

I'd like to know how to remove the style of tag "a" in the child element "i".

obs: I'm using Awesome icons.

Comment: css styles `a#idSomething>i { text-decoration:none }`

Comment: or inline 
`<a href="#idSomething"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down fa-3x" style="text-decoration:none"></i></a> `

Comment: text-decoration didn't work, using inline style with the color attribute make what I want, but I don't want to use inline style.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to view what are the styles applied to your i tag, which is luckily easy to do in modern browsers and then override the rules, like

```
#idSomething > i {
    /*Your rules*/
}
```

Comment: the element is without any customized style, the color is from the parent tag "a". If I set inline color style, I can make what I want, but I don't want to use the inline style

Comment: @ThiagoNunesBatista then you might want to override the rules for #idSomething